# Why CallbackFlow is running on main thread

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am using callback flow in my code to retrieve data from Firebase Database. Here is my code

```
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  suspend fun getUserOrder() = callbackFlow<UserOrder>{
            println("Current Thread name is ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            databaseReference.child("Order").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d("database error ",error.message)
                    channel.close(error.toException())
                }

                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        snapshot.children.forEach { data ->
                            data.children.forEach {newData->
                                newData.children.forEach { childData->
                                    val userOrder = UserOrder(
                                        childData.key!!,
                                        childData.child("item_name").value as String,
                                        childData.child("item_price").value as String,
                                        childData.child("item_quantity").value as String,
                                        childData.child("item_weight").value as String
                                    )
                                    offer(userOrder)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        channel.close()
                    }
                }
            })
        awaitClose()
    } 

//Activity class code
  viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            viewModel.getOrder().collect {
                println("Item id is ${it.item_id}")
            }
        }
        println("Total time taken is $time")
    }
```

Data is retrieving but it is running on main thread. I wanna run it on background thread. How is it possible?. Tell me anybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You launched your coroutine with the [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel).viewModelScope:kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope), which is "bound to `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`".
That's why your coroutines runs in the main thread.

To jump threads, you can use [`withContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html).

The [`IO` dispatcher](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) can be used for thread-blocking calls, which I do not see in the given code.

Comment: Can you give an example? Cause you can't wrap the callbackFlow in a withContext(Dispatcher.IO) block or append an .flowOn(DIspatcher.IO) operator.